# "winmdexp.exe" exited with code -532462766

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Scenario: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate release 4. Windows 8.1 Universal Project. C#. I need a Windows Runtime Component to update my Live Tile periodically.
The solution build ends with the error message:

> "winmdexp.exe" exited with code -532462766

I've been searching for clues for the past 2-1/2 days. Nothing comes close. There are no syntax errors in any of the code anywhere in the three projects in this solution. Can anyone point me in a direction at least?

Comment: This seems potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278050/windows-metadata-exporter-crashes-when-compiling-windows-runtime-component

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution. My Windows and Windows Phone projects have Assembly Version settings of 1, 0, *, and -blank- to automatically generate version numbers as a function of date-compiled. I use the automatically-generated version numbers to get a "date-compiled" at run-time.

When I set the Assembly Version settings in the runtime component project to match those of the other two projects in the solution, the above error message just went away! :)

Since this was such an ugly problem with no extant solution that I could find, anywhere, I figured I would post a solution here and save somebody else 2-1/2 days of work.

Answer (score 0):

If it will help someone - to see the the real error description open `cmd` and run `bin\Debug\YourProject.exe`